# Install Play Framework on Linux Server via FileZilla

Tags: java, playframework, installation, server, filezilla

I feel pretty dumb to ask this, but I have made a webapp with the Play Framework and don't know how to get it working on my server.

As I have no experience with servers I downloaded FileZilla and simply uploaded the files of my PlayApp.

Can anyone help me and tell me how I can upload my Project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the version of play you use?

Comment: I think its 2.2 or 2.3 :)

Comment: Do you use `activator` command?

Comment: Sorry, I did never use that I always started my activator with the batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `sbt` run `sbt clean stage`. You can run `clean stage` with `activator` as well. In your project root directory locate `target/universal/stage` directory. It contains content of your app including all dependencies and play framework itself. You can run your app from bin directory. There are scripts for linux and windows. More details: playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Production